# How to subtract two consecutive elements in an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, enumeration

I have an array of meter readings in my iPhone app. I have been trying to calculate consumptions by iterating through the array and substracting two consecutive elements. I have tried it several ways but I always refer to an index out of bounds.

This is my latest attempt at getting the consumption:

```
    NSMutableArray *mutableConsumption = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    int i = 0;
    while (i < [readings count]) {
        for (int j = 1; j < [readings count]; j++) {
            NSLog(@"i: %i, j: %i", i, j);
            NSNumber *prev = [[readings objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"value"];
            NSNumber *this = [[readings objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"value"];
            float consumed = [this floatValue] - [prev floatValue];
            NSLog(@"consumed: %f", consumed);

            [mutableConsumption addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:consumed]];
            i++;
        }
    }
```

For the record a Reading object is a Core Data entity which has a float for its `value` key (which is stored as an NSNumber by Core Data).

This is what I'm getting printed into the console:

```
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.305 Csekkolj[4608:c07] HEATING readings.count: 13
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.305 Csekkolj[4608:c07] i: 0, j: 1
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.306 Csekkolj[4608:c07] consumed: 58.416016
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.306 Csekkolj[4608:c07] i: 1, j: 2
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.306 Csekkolj[4608:c07] consumed: 38.247070
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.307 Csekkolj[4608:c07] i: 2, j: 3
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.307 Csekkolj[4608:c07] consumed: 25.605957
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.307 Csekkolj[4608:c07] i: 3, j: 4
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.307 Csekkolj[4608:c07] consumed: 29.143066
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.308 Csekkolj[4608:c07] i: 4, j: 5
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.308 Csekkolj[4608:c07] consumed: 23.701904
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.308 Csekkolj[4608:c07] i: 5, j: 6
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.309 Csekkolj[4608:c07] consumed: 29.482178
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.309 Csekkolj[4608:c07] i: 6, j: 7
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.309 Csekkolj[4608:c07] consumed: 53.989990
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.310 Csekkolj[4608:c07] i: 7, j: 8
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.310 Csekkolj[4608:c07] consumed: 97.111816
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.311 Csekkolj[4608:c07] i: 8, j: 9
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.311 Csekkolj[4608:c07] consumed: 157.211182
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.312 Csekkolj[4608:c07] i: 9, j: 10
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.312 Csekkolj[4608:c07] consumed: 187.606934
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.312 Csekkolj[4608:c07] i: 10, j: 11
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.313 Csekkolj[4608:c07] consumed: 183.083008
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.313 Csekkolj[4608:c07] i: 11, j: 12
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.313 Csekkolj[4608:c07] consumed: 143.708008
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.314 Csekkolj[4608:c07] i: 12, j: 1
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.315 Csekkolj[4608:c07] consumed: -968.891113
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.315 Csekkolj[4608:c07] i: 13, j: 2
    2013-04-26 20:08:16.316 Csekkolj[4608:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[_PFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (13) beyond bounds (13)'
```

I understand that there is no array index #13 as an array with 13 elements is indexed from 0 to 12. But when I try running the while loop until `i < [readings count]-1` I get the same result only the index out of bounds is one lower, 12.
Also, why does the for loop start looping from 1 again?

I know this is probably not even an Objective-C question but rather to do with algorithms but I'm struggling with it for a while now so I would be very grateful if someone could point out the obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last valid index in the array, as you're aware, is `count-1`, but you actually want to stop your loop at one element before that, because there's no next element to form a pair for subtraction.

Your loop should look something like this:

```
NSUInteger count = [array count];
for( NSUInteger i = 0; i <= (count - 2); i++ ){
    id curr = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    id next = [array objectAtIndex:i+1];

    // Calculate...
}
```

This way you will get the last element, the one at index `count-1`, in the final iteration as `next`.

Comment: Thank you! I think I have tried this one too I just didn't know anymore. Now it seems my code is wrong at a different array too because I am getting some method calls (by Core Plot) after my calculations and eventually I get another out of bounds exception.

Also, if I am right, I miss one consumption data as the last one I now get is 183.083008. Sorry if I didn't get your explanation right but why did I lose the last one (143.xxx)?

Comment: I'm not sure. Are you certain that you're supposed to be getting that result? Have your checked the pairs by hand?

Comment: Yes, I added the same readings that I have in a spreadsheet and got the same consumptions.